# Pressing the browser back button undoes my state instead of going back

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

My React website has a video carousel with "Next" and "Prev" buttons used to cycle through the various videos. I save the URL of the current video being displayed in state. That way, when the "Next" or "Prev" buttons are pressed, I just update the state with the appropriate video URL and that video is displayed.

For some reason, the browser back button now undoes all the state changes one by one before going back to the previous page. So if, for instance, I press "Next","Next","Next, I would have to press the browser back button 4 times before I'm taken to the previous page. I cannot figure out why, and I have Googled myself blind trying to solve this issue.

Function that is called when the user presses either of the buttons:

```
const changeVideo = (dir) => {
        let index = movie.videoUrls.findIndex(v => v === currentVideo)
            //movie.videoUrls contains the URLs of all the videos to be displayed
        if(dir === 'next') {
            if(index === movie.videoUrls.length - 1)
                setCurrentVideo(movie.videoUrls[0])
            else
                setCurrentVideo(movie.videoUrls[index+1])
            return;
        }
        if(dir === 'prev') {
            if(index === 0)
                setCurrentVideo(movie.videoUrls[movie.videoUrls.length - 1])
            else
                setCurrentVideo(movie.videoUrls[index-1])
            return;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** The video being displayed is a YouTube embed, if that matters.

Comment: Can you please create a codesandbox and recreate this issue

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-browser-16zdx?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-browser-16zdx?file=/src/App.js)
Open the app in a new window rather than the built-in codeSandbox browser to see the issue. Click the 'Next' or 'Prev'  button a few times and press the browser back button to see the issue in action. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a key to the iframe otherwise it will mess up with the react router

Just add currentVideo state as a key to YoutubeEmbed Component

Here is the link to updated sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-brook-zqht1?file=/src/App.js